# Connecting ARM cortex m4 to the internet

Tags: microcontroller, arm

So I would like to connect my arm cortex M4 Microcontroller from TI to the internet through the home network. The purpose is so that i can remotely control something, lets just say an LED. Where should i start and what is the cheapest method.
Please note that I am not transmitting large amounts of data nor do i need it to be super secure as security is not an a major issue. Basically I just want to control about six or seven sensors and read their data remotely.
What are your suggestions and where do you think i should start
Thanks every

Comment: Also, i need the connections to be wireless. Please note that i am familiar with TCP/IP protocol and all basic electrical engineering topics. (BSEE)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Various companies (including TI, Murata and Microchip) offer ready-to-go Wifi modules that can interface with a microcontroller via SPI or UART.  Search for CC3000, SN8200, RN171 respectively.  If you're prepared to go further down into the protocol stack murk, they're mostly using Wifi chipsets with SDIO interfaces.  If you're after throughput, the Murata SN820x is nice, but be prepared to write your own SPI stack.  The TI CC3000 is substantially slower (TI claim about 3Mbps of TCP throughput), but iirc they have a free stack that should integrate easily with a TI M4.

Comment: Before you go with the CC3000 you might want to look at the [CC3000 forum] (http://e2e.ti.com/support/low_power_rf/f/851.aspx) and all the bugs the current firmware has. I tried and failed building a stable application (just like many others)